# Vue iframe recursively reload fonts

Tags: css, vue.js, iframe, fonts

I have iframe component that load old site pages based on vue route, but sometime its jump to load recursively fonts.

```
<iframe
   v-if="src"
   :src="src"
/>
```

files that recursively reloaded:

- `/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0`
- `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v16/XRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaB.woff2`

in 5 minutes +/- 4000 requests in total

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the iframe is loading itself again and again, therefore loading fonts, etc?

You could identify the iframe and make a check to be sure it doesn't load more than it needs to.

Comment: the problem that its dont reload iframe content, it also reload fonts and not every tyme. The bug dont apear on first load, but can apear after (+/-)5 page changes or (+/-)10 or dont apear.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in infinite change of element `<style>`.

```js
style.innerHTML = `
    body {
        top: ${e.data.offset.top}px !important;
        right: ${e.data.offset.right}px !important;
        bottom: ${e.data.offset.bottom}px !important;
        left: ${e.data.offset.left}px !important;
    }
`;
```

But whi that simple change of style reload font i dont know.